# Ionic won't show external image, even with (seemingly) proper whitelisting

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get my Ionic app to download images from my website, but keep getting a 404 (or a code 3 for my download function), where the image does exists when viewed in a browser.

```
<img ng-src="http://www.example.com/images/cool-picture.jpg" width="100" />
```

This problem is for all (tested) resources, images, css and javascript files. About every topic about this tell you to set whitelist options and config values, I'm currently at this point:

```
<!-- config.xml: -->
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />

<!-- index.html -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

- White-list version: 1.3.0, cordova 6.4.0, ionic 1.
- I control the `example.com` from this example.
- I've copied the config.xml from a working project (and set the app_id etc correct), no result
- I've copied the index.html from a working project, not working smooth, and also not loaded the external resources that work in the working project
- When I start a new project I can load the external image without any effort

Answer (score 0):

I have this is in my index.html and it displays everything no matter what

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src *;
        img-src * data: blob:;
        object-src 'self' blob:;
        style-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;;
        script-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">
```

Comment: I asume I need to replace the `&apos;` for `'`, but that doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: To be sure I left the `&apos;` as is, still not working

Comment: what content type is blocked.. can  u copy paste your browser console error. &apos; is for single quote. If the error is 404 , that means the image is not there in the location. Also if you are using UNIX based system, they are case sensitive so check the extension JPG or jpg

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it's an image and it returns a 404. The image does exists when I open it in my browser. Just tried adding a JS and a CSS file too, also arent working (404), but in my browser the exact link works